# RxJS: exhaustMap in V8

Tags: rxjs

According to the document the `exhaustMap` uses an ResultSelector and this will be removed in V8. I tried to follow the [example](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/resultSelector) but couldn't make a clue how to refactor my code.

```
interval(5000)
  .pipe(
    takeWhile(() => !this.isDialogDestroyed),
    exhaustMap(() => this.versService.checkStatus(myParameters))
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (status) => {
      if (status === 'DONE') {
        this.isDialogDestroyed = true;
        // ...  further processing - removed for simplicity 
      }
    },
    error: () => {
      // Handle errors here
    },
  });
```

How to adapt the code to be ready for V8?

Comment: what's the return type of `versService.checkStatus()` ?

Comment: Some kind of enum for the `status`, e.g. `FetchStatus`.

Comment: It's an observable right ?

Comment: Btw your code doesn't use the deprecated signature of `exhaustMap` which takes 2 argments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're not using the result selector yourself (second argument of `exhaustMap`) there's nothing you'll have to do in regards this for this code to be compatible in V8.

In your example you can see the suggestion they make is to replace the second parameter from `switchMap` into piping a `map` on the result:

```js
import { fromEvent, switchMap, interval, map } from 'rxjs';

// deprecated
fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(
  switchMap((x) => interval(1000), (_, x) => x + 1)
);
// suggested change
fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(
  switchMap((x) => interval(1000).pipe(map((x) => x + 1)))
);
```

If we [check the docs on `exhaustMap` operator](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/exhaustMap):

```js
function exhaustMap<T, R, O extends ObservableInput<any>>(project: (value: T, index: number) => O, resultSelector?: (outerValue: T, innerValue: ObservedValueOf<O>, outerIndex: number, innerIndex: number) => R): OperatorFunction<T, ObservedValueOf<O> | R>
```

Second argument `resultSelector?: (outerValue: T, innerValue: ObservedValueOf<O>, outerIndex: number, innerIndex: number) => R` will be removed, therefore don't use it.

Since the snippet you've pasted doesn't make use of it there's no action for you to take :)

Comment: Thank you for clarification - then I need to blame the linting tool :-|